# Empty or too short HTTP message using HTTPRequest

Tags: php, post, file-upload, httprequest

I have an app that responds to a POST request with files:

https://docxgenjs.herokuapp.com/

It just echoes out (in JSON format) the files that were posted to that URL.

You can test it using a REST Console (on chrome web store).

Howewer, when I request that page using PHP, it doesn't work out:

```
try { 
    $url = 'https://docxgenjs.herokuapp.com/';
    $request = new HTTPRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST); 
    $request->addPostFile("config",app_path()."\\docxgen\\config.json"); 
    $request->addPostFile("docx",app_path()."\\docxgen\\tagExample.docx"); 
    $request->send();
    $response = $request->getResponseBody();
    var_dump($response);
} 
catch(Exception $e) 
{
    var_dump($e->getMessage()); var_dump($e->getCode());
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
string(35) "Empty or too short HTTP message: ''"
int(2)
```

What's different between the two POST Requests, and how can I fix that ?

If I remove the two lines:

```
$request->addPostFile("config",app_path()."\\docxgen\\config.json"); 
$request->addPostFile("docx",app_path()."\\docxgen\\tagExample.docx");
```

They is no exception and the response of the server is the expected response `{}`

Comment: Are you sure the addPostFile paths are correct?

Comment: Oh, shit you were right seems that the paths must be given with normal slashes `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the paths had to be written with `/` rather than `\\`